# RESTful Quiz Representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm building a quiz. A user can pick a subject and answer 5 questions. After each question they view the answer. I'm trying to stick to a strict RESTful representation of this workflow but cant really settle on a url scheme. For example:

User Joe picks the subject sport and is ready to see the first question. The url is

```
user/joe/subject/sport/question/1
```

When he submits his answer 'B' ( its a multiple choice quiz) , Joe is creating a new answer, we POST to

```
user/joe/subject/sport/question/1/answer/B
```

before viewing the correct answer at

```
user/joe/subject/sport/answer/1
```

we then view the next question at

```
user/joe/subject/sport/question/2
```

This is all obviously too complicated. How would you approach this problem in a RESTful manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-phpday11-20110514). It's is a great resource for RESTful API design. With that in mind, here are some starting suggestions:

1. RESTful URLs have an implicit hierarchy. Take the user information out of the URL. It belongs in the HTTP headers.

   ```
   /subject/sport/question/1
   /subject/sport/question/1/answer/B
   /subject/sport/answer/1
   /subject/sport/question/2
   ```
2. I don't see any useful information added by the `subject` part. The `subject` is identified by (in your example) `sport`.

   ```
   /sport/question/1
   /sport/question/1/answer/B
   /sport/answer/1
   /sport/question/2
   ```
3. Categories should be plural.

   ```
   /sports/questions/1
   /sports/questions/1/answers/B
   /sports/answers/1
   /sports/questions/2
   ```
4. When you POST to answer a question, you're not POSTing to *add a new answer resource* (that is, defining a new possible answer). Aren't you are POSTing to an existing resource?
5. You haven't mentioned anything about HATEOAS. If you're *really* going to implement REST, you should be doing things like [providing "next" links *in the hypermedia.*](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-phpday11-20110514/124)

Comment: MДΓΓ, Can you clarify point 4? It makes a lot of sense but what resource would you POST to?

Comment: I'm not sure, which is why I didn't go too far into it. Perhaps something like `POST /sports/answers?question=1`?

Answer (score 1):

For me the basic idea in a REST service is the "resource". First you need to identify your resources.

So there is a user and she starts a new quiz.

- POST /user/joe/quiz.
- It returns: Location: /user/joe/quiz/1

Then the user selects a sports question, so you update your quiz to include a random (server selected) question.

- POST /user/joe/quiz/1 -> Subject:sport
- It returns: Location: /user/joe/quiz/1/question/1

The user answers:

- PUT /user/joe/quiz/1/question/1 -> Answer B

Now rinse and repeat.

The resources we've got:

- Users
- Quiz for a user
- Questions in a Quiz (The question is updated with an answer)

Comment: PUTs should be idempotent. I'm not sure that answering a question is.

Comment: I use POST to create and PUT to update (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `/user/joe` from the routes entirely. You can get the current_user using Devise, Authlogic, or some other authentication framework.

Otherwise this looks okay to me, as it's only two nests which is readable enough. So you'd have:

```
GET subjects/sports/questions/1
POST subjects/sports/questions/1 # pass along params with {:answer => 'B'}
GET subjects/sports/answers/1
```